# Using puppeteer or playwright, is there a way to update the args initially passed in the launch method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, headless-browser

I want to update the source of the file passed to the arg `--use-file-for-fake-video-capture`. Is there a way to update it after the browser instance has been initialized or will this require me to reinitialize the instance with the new source of the file?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to modify launch args once the Chromium instance is running. Not even with [`puppeteer.connect()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-puppeteerconnectoptions) to an existing browser instance, as it doesn't accept `args` the same way as [`puppeteer.launch()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-puppeteerconnectoptions). You will need to relaunch the browser.